# How do I setup more then 10 loopback device?

Tags: linux, devices, loop-device

From this answer the solution is to

```
modprobe loop max_loop=64
```

Which makes me allowed to use 64 loopback devices then

```
mknod -m 660 /dev/loop8 b 7 8
```

To create the devices. I did this for 8, 9, 10 and 8,9 works but 10 does not.

I then tried loopa to loopf and tried to mount a 11th device and i get the error

```
Error: Failed to set up a loop device:
```

How do I make >10 loop devices?

Comment: Make sure you are running `mknod -m 660 /dev/loop10 b 7 10`.  It worked fine for me. What distribution are you using?

Comment: @sparticvs: oops, I have been using 8 as the last value for all vars. I wonder why it let me mount my 9th and 10 device if i did it incorrectly. I use ubuntu, i'm testing right now. yep it worked. I'll accept if you answer

Comment: You can make multiple filesystem entries for the same device. They all designate the same device. You got this error when you called `losetup` or `mount -o loop` on a loop device that's already in use (even if you reach that device through a different name).

Comment: What I don't like about this question is that its not asking how to tell if max_loop was set to 64 properly.  And nowhere am I able to find information on how to tell what max is set to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you are running `mknod -m 660 /dev/loop10 b 7 10`. The format is `mknod -m 660 /dev/loop<ID> b 7 <ID>` where ID is the same.

**Update [07/10/2014]**

I also found a good blog post to always have more at boot. See https://yeri.be/xen-failed-to-find-an-unused-loop-device

**Update [05/25/2016]**

I run a CentOS server, and I found that [this post](http://thelinuxfaq.com/141-increase-loop-devices-in-centos-6-rhel-6-centos-5) was also helpful when the other methods don't work.

This makes my new favorite method:

```
MAKEDEV /dev/loop
```

It creates 256 loop devices (which is the max without modifying the kernel).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a free major loop device number amidst non-numbered loop device names(e.g. `/dev/loop-something`), you can use this command to find the biggest one and add 1:

`find /dev -type b -print0 | xargs -0L1 bash -c 'stat -c "%t %T" "$1" | awk "/^7 / { print(\$2); }"' '' | sort -nru | head -n1`